# How to use Vuetify text field slot?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to append a button outside of vuetify text field and i am trying to use the `append` slot but not sure how to do it. If someone can help me with that, i sure would appreciate it.

Please check this simple [demo](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/yLYEpda).

or as an alternative this demo below:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {};
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout>
        <v-text-field solo placeholder="you@email.com">
          <template slot="append">
            <v-btn>Hellloooo!!!</v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-text-field>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you want to remove the button with the text "Hellloooo" outside the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append-outer` slot:

```
<v-text-field solo placeholder="you@email.com">
    <template slot="append-outer">
        <v-btn>Hellloooo!!!</v-btn>
    </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Check slot tab to see all options: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#api